# How can I solve this integral using residue theorom?

Tags: residue-calculus

$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\sin ⁡x}{(1+\frac{1}{2}\cos x)} dx
$$
I want to solve this.

I have solved this here in the image but I have not reached a real number

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: There's absoluteny no chance of understanding anything in the picture. Please use MathJax to write the equations.

Comment: Is this the integral that you want to calculate?
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\sin \theta}{1+\frac{\cos \theta}{2}}\, d\theta
$$

Comment: yes sir i would appreciate it if you solve it tnx.

Comment: Perhaps you can see the integrand in the form $g'(x) \cdot f'(g(x))$ ? (at least if you multiply the integrand by $-\frac{1}{2}$)

Comment: i want to solve it with sinx=1/2(z+1/z). could you please guide me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Recall $\sin(\theta)=\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}$ and $\cos(\theta)=\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}$. Use the substitution $z= e^{i\theta} $ then, $dz = i e^{i\theta}  d\theta$.

The integral becomes:

$$  \frac{2}i\oint_C \frac{(z-1/z)dz}{4+z+1/z} = \frac{2}i\oint_C \frac{(z^2 -1)dz}{z^2 + 4z +1} $$ where $C$ is the unit circle around the origin.
The poles of the denominator appear to be at $z_{\pm} = -2 \pm \sqrt{3} $. Hence, we see that our contour includes only $z_{+}$.

$Res(z_{+})=-2 + \sqrt{3}$. This implies $I=4 \pi (-2 + \sqrt{3})$. We need the imaginer part of this result since the initial integral was containing $sin(x)=Im[e^{i \theta}].$ Finally,

$\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\sin ⁡x}{(1+\frac{1}{2}\cos x)} dx =0.$

Comment: thank you very much